# problems with Array.prototype.indexOf.call

Tags: javascript

If i click the a element "Link1" e.target in the function is the node Link1. I want to know in what index this node is in the ul children in this case i want indexOf to return 0 because Link1 is on position 0, and i i click 2 i want it to be 1.

HTML

```
<div class="link">
    <ul>
       <li><a>Link1</a></li>
       <li><a>Link2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
self.query('.link').forEach(function(linkNode, flikIndex, flikArr) { 
    dojo.query(linkNode, 'click', function(e) {
        var t = e.target; //If i click Link1 this is Link1 and if i click Link2 and so on. 
        var parent = t.parentNode; //Contains the parent to my a in this case li 
        var ancestor = t.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes; //Containes 2 li 
        var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent, ancestor); //Return -1 but i want it to return 0 because Link1 is on place [0] in the array.             

    }
}
```

Please help me get the right index

Comment: I suspect you want `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(ancestor, parent)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent, ancestor);
//                                       ^ Array ^ Element in the array
```

So you want this:

```
var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(ancestor, parent);
```

Since `ancestor` is the element ("array") that contains `parent`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let nodes = Array.from( parent.closest('ul').children);
let index = nodes.indexOf(li);
```

When we work with a NodeList, getting the index of the li can be tricky using this approach:

```
var ancestor = t.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes; 
var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(ancestor, parent);
```

If we have text in the lis, then these are also considered childNodes, and so the index of the li which is returned will be its index in the nodeList which consists of other children such as text, and not merely other lis. Therefore, you may not be getting the desired result in case you are only interested in the position of an li relative to the other lis in the ul