# Getting index of element clicked with Array.prototype.indexof.call();

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the index of the element clicked but for some reason I always get -1. I tried putting the parent as first parameter and the ancestor as second and vice versa but it doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

HTML Example:

```
<div>One</div>
<div>Two</div>
```

JS Example:

```
function elementNr(target, parent) {
  console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent, target));
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if(e.target != e.currentTarget) {
    elementNr(e.target, this)
  }
});
```

I got the idea from this post: [problems with Array.prototype.indexOf.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167628/problems-with-array-prototype-indexof-call)

I wanted to see if this works with event delegation like the example above.

**Goal:** Using event delegation and Array.prototype I want to get the index of the element clicked.

Comment: It seems you are trying to treat a DOM element as an array. That can't work. What do you mean by "index of the element"? Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What are you checking for?

Comment: Uhm, I don't see how that would ever work, even if you convert `parent`, which is just the body, to an array, why would `target` ever be in that array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167628/problems-with-array-prototype-indexof-call

Comment: @FelixKling yes of course. Here is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167628/problems-with-array-prototype-indexof-call

Comment: @adeneo ya im a bit confused there. I got the basic idea from the link I just posted

Comment: X/Y problem? What is the aim of the code

Comment: @mplungjan title says: get index of element clicked

Comment: @Asperger - the example you link to gets the `childNodes`, converts that nodeList to an array, and checks with indexOf if an element is inside that array, it's not the same thing

Comment: @Asperger: Neither `this` nor `e.target` is an array (or array-like object).  They are both *one* single element, not a collection of elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185738/how-to-find-the-position-for-an-element-in-a-li-with-jquery-or-vanilla-js#answer-18191104

Comment: @RocketHazmat oh crap, you are right as e.target returns the actual element but how do I get the index? Really my bad, im aware of it but you know, mind block xD

Comment: The index of what? Is the target a direct child of document.body, and do you want the index related to it's siblings, or do you want the index of the element based on nested elements, i.e. the entire body, or do you want the index of the element based on it's parent, regardless of what that is, and the siblings .... or ....

Comment: it is a direct child of document.body.  So if I click on a div of lets say class="test" I want it to return the index.

Comment: `[].slice.call(document.body.children).indexOf(target)`

Comment: @adeneo you are right, I saw that on stackoverflow before.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/btkyu8wr/

Comment: @adeneo unless you are a programming samurai you might want to post it as an answer just in case.

Comment: No worries, I am in fact a programming samurai, just don't tell anyone.